# Trouble in updating database record in access with c#

Tags: c#, ms-access, sql-update

I am working with a program which stores customers data 
and later it needs to be changed

this is my code :

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)       
{
        conn.Open();
        string oc = ("Update Custs Set Cname =@Cname, NatCode=@NatCode, Bdate=@Bdate, CellPhone=@CellPhone, Addr=@Addr,  Where NatCode Like'%" + textBox2.Text + "%'");

        OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand();
        myCommand.CommandText = oc;
        myCommand.Connection = conn;
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cname",textBox1.Text);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NatCode", textBox3.Text);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Bdate", textBox2.Text);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CellPhone", textBox4.Text);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Addr", textBox8.Text);

        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        conn.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Data Changed successfully!");

        }
```

But it doesn't do change anything

any help would be appreciated

Comment: You have coma before Where also there is no space after Like. Also put the like content in parameter too.

Comment: Might only be my opinion, but to me, naming textboxes `textBox1` through `textBox8` is a terrible choice... Why wouldn't you name those according to what they are supposed to contain ? (also noticed the `button2` inside the method name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure `Where NatCode Like'%" + textBox2.Text + "%'"` contains any row?

in `myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Bdate", textBox2.Text);` you are using `textBox2` for `Birthday` and in Query you use it for `NationalCode`.

I guess the problem is it.